# Proof verification -- If a $(k[x]/\langle x^n \rangle)$-module $M$ has a finite free resolution, then $M$ is free.

Tags: solution-verification, commutative-algebra, modules

This is an exercise (Exercise 1.23) in Eisenbud. I am not very familiar with free modules, nor resolutions, so I was wondering if this proof was accurate. I have some suspicions, but I figured it would be better to defer to experts.

**Proposition:** If $M$ is a $(k[x]/\langle x^n \rangle)$-module with finite free resolution, then $M$ is free.

*Potential Proof*:

Let $R = k[x]/\langle x^n \rangle$, and suppose that $M$ has a finite free resolution:

$$0 \to R^{n_l} \to R^{n_{l-1}} \to \dots \to R^{n_1} \to R^{n_0} \to M \to 0$$

This induces a free resolution $\mathcal{F} : 0 \to R^z \to R^{n_0} \to M \to 0$, where $z = \sum_{i=1}^l (-1)^{i+1} n_i$. Since the map $R^z \to R^{n_0}$ is a monomorphism, after a change of variables we may consider it the inclusion into the first $z$ coordinates of $R^{n_0}$, so it has a retract in the projection sending elements of $R^{n_0}$ to their first $z$ coordinates. As $\mathcal{F}$'s first nontrivial morphism has a retract, $\mathcal{F}$ is split, so:

$$R^{n_0} \cong M \oplus R^z$$

Since $x^n$ annihilates $R^k$ for any $k$, we multiply both sides by $1^{\oplus n_0-z} \oplus (x^n)^{\oplus z}$ to obtain $R^{n_0 - z} \cong M$, as desired. $\square$

Is this proof correct? If not, where is it incorrect?

Comment: Why does the given resolution induce a resolution $0\to R^z\to R^{n_0}\to M\to 0$?

Comment: Also, how do you know that you can make a change of variables to turn $R^z\to R^{n_0}$ into the inclusion of the first $z$ coordinates?

Comment: I think I was working with vector space intuition which does not work here. Do you have a hint as to the correct strategy?

Comment: The usual argument is: (1) given a finite free resolution over a local ring, you can "minimize" it to get one where all the entries of the matrices are in the maximal ideal; (2) here the maximal ideal is nilpotent, say $m^n = 0$, so $m^{n-1}$ annihilates the image of every map by (1); and (3) the last map $0 \to R^{n_l} \to R^{n_l-1}$ is a monomorphism, so its image is a free $R$-module, which cannot be annihilated by $m^{n-1}$